# audio not record in android webrtc local stream?

Tags: android, audio, webrtc, mediastream

I face one error in android activity please help to solve it. I have used libjingle library for webrtc android.

**Error is :-**

> status -38
>    WebRtcAudioRecord: AudioRecord.startRecording failed
>   StartRecording failed!
>   WebRtcAudioRecord: InitRecording() called twice without StopRecording()
>   InitRecording failed!

first time working perfectly but when i back from video calling activity to home activity and again come to video activity then give error.

In this scenario video perfectly working but audio not record.

I have get both audio and video from remote stream but local stream only take video and send to ice candidate but audio not recored.

how to solve it ? please help me out.

thank you.

Comment: Have you solved it?